# Response times from far locations grows rapidly under load

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

We have a simple Java web application and we are performance testing it with a test case, where we upload a 1 MB file to the application under test. We have several locations around the world where we can test it. From some far locations the transaction response time seems to grow very fast under load, but from most places it stays steady. The used load is not high and network shouldn't be a limiting factor. What else could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Your remote network saturation is the limiting factor.

If it was inbound then all locations using the same inbound interface would be subject to the delay.  As you indicate that only some of the locations are impacted we can use the non impacted as control elements of the test to determine that it is not the common inbound interface.